# Bash formatting inside the cycle do

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a format in a variable that is included in the cycle. The format should be "a000", "a001", and so on. The only using echo ${parameter} should output a1, a2. How I can set the formatting inside ${}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` instead of `echo`.

```
$ for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
> printf 'a%03d\n' "$i"
> done
a000
a001
a002
a003
a004
a005
a006
a007
a008
a009
a010
```

`%03d` pads the number on the right with 0 to make a 3-digit number.